# Parallelization of the method for finding the determinant of a matrix on MPI

Tags: c, mpi

How can you implement to parallelize the method for finding the determinant of the matrix on the MPI? How to parallelize the filling of the matrix, is it possible to pass data from the previous process to each process, and how can I apply this to my code?

```
double GaussDet(double** mat, int size) {

    int determinant = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = i; k < size; ++k)
        {
            for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; --j)
            {
                mat[k][j] -= mat[k][i - 1] / mat[i - 1][i - 1] * mat[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if(i == j)
        determinant *= mat[i][j];
      }
    }
    return determinant;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{ 
    srand(time(NULL));
    int N = 4;

    double **matrix = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      matrix[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
    }
    fill_matrix(matrix, N);
    print_matrix(matrix, N);
    double det = GaussDet(matrix, N);
    print_matrix(matrix, N);
    printf("det = %f\n", det);
 
}
```

Comment: `int determinant = 1;` is strange.  Why `int`?

Comment: Avoid sizing errors as in `matrix[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));`.  Instead size to the referenced value: `matrix[i] = malloc(N * sizeof matrix[i][0]);`.

Comment: "how can I apply this to my code?" --> I recommend to get code to function correctly first as one process before attempting multiple ones.

Comment: So he does it right. Or if there are errors where? besides memory, I corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing computing the determinant by doing a reduction to upper triangular form, and then multiplying the elements on the diagonal. The upper triangular reduction is the basis of Gaussian elimination (or: computing the LU factorization), so let's pretend that's what you asked for.

Ok, so you have a matrix and you have MPI. MPI uses distributed memory, so for a good implementation you'd need to distribute your matrix. The easiest solution is to let each process have a number of distinct rows stored. Columns is possible too, but this makes no difference to the argument.

Gaussian elimination has a lot of paralellism, but it has one sequential component: the calculation of the `1/a[i,i]` pivots. You do that for one value of `i`, update all matrix elements, do it for the next `i`, et cetera. The important thing to notice is that only one process has that element stored, and so only one process knows the value of the pivot. So that process has to broadcast it to all others. And then everyone can update their matrix elements.

Start by coding that: each process get a slice of the matrix, and then you compute the factorization thusly.

Now, this algorithm has problems: after you've eliminated pivot `i`, the process that stores it is no longer active. So in the course of the factorization, your parallelism will get less and less. You can solve this by giving each process not a block slice of the matrix, but rows by round-robin. There is a further problem, harder to describe, with the basic assumption of assigning whole rows to a process.

As a result, high quality implementations of this algorithm are very rare. Scalapack and PLapack (both 1990s), and then Elemental (2010s) are really just about the only ones. Goes to show how tricky this problem is. But the basis should be doable as I outlined above.

Comment: Okay, thanks, can you tell me where you can read, for example, about the pararellism of quicksort?

Comment: I found an example, but it works very badly, and for example, for 50-100 elements, it simply displays errors or an array with unknown values [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-quick-sort-using-mpi-omp-and-posix-thread/)

Comment: If you're trying to learn MPI you're going about it the wrong way. Quicksort is *extremely* hard to do with MPI. So what are you trying to do? (Btw, thanks for upvoting and accepting my answer. Hint.)

Comment: And you realize that quicksort is a completely different question?

Comment: Yes, I understand. No, I do not study MPI, but the assignment of the course project is associated with it. There were several options, I thought quick sort might be easier, since even the code is on the Internet, but as it turned out, it only works on the data in the example. Can I create a new question about her, is it worth it?

Comment: I looked at your link. It's not really quicksort: each process does a local quicksort and then they do a merge sort. The code looks ok. Anyway. If your course requires you to do an MPI assignment, do something simple like a stencil computation. There are a million tutorials for that.

Comment: Can you please tell me if we do such operations after quick sorting?  if (rank_of_process % (2 * step) != 0) {
            MPI_Send(...) } and  if (rank_of_process + step < number_of_process). In my quicksort link

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I'll try to create a new question, maybe it will be clearer this way